# Are pointers used when copying a class with huge array member?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, return

I have a class storing an multidimensional array as member.

```
struct Structure
{
    Structure()
    {
        memset(Data, 0, sizeof Data);
    }

    int Number;
    int Data[32][32][32];
}
```

When I write a function returning an object of this `Structure`, are all the bytes if the `Data` member copied or is just a reference passed?

```
Structure Create(int Parameter)
{
    Structure structure;

    // modify structure based on parameter
    // ...

    return structure;
}
```

If that results in copying the whole block of data, how can I do better? And what would it change to allocate the object on the heap like `Structure *structure = new Structure();` and returning that pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return the object by value, the actual data (32<sup>3</sup> `int`s) will be copied. It's possible the compiler will optimise away the copy (so called "copy elision"), but that is never guaranteed.

If you allocate the object dynamically and return a pointer to it, there will be no copying, of course. If you have access to C++11, consider returning a `std::unique_ptr`, so that ownership is clear and there's no chance of memory leaks.

In C++11, you could also "do better" by turning the member `Data` into a conainer (such as `std::vector`) which internally stores its data on the heap and has move semantics. This means that when returning from a function, the container will be moved instead of copied, and data will not be duplicated.

Comment: Didn't know that about `std::vector` either. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @danijar Just to clarify, all C++11 standard library containers which store their data dynamically are move-enabled. Not just `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

When you return an object by value the object will not actually be copied, instead your function will populate the object directly in the callers memory. It's as if you did the following:

```
Structure s;
Create(Parameter, &s);
```

Although a little better as the default constructor doesn't even get called. This is called "return value optimisation". Although it's not guarenteed by the standard, it is performed by all mainstream C++ compilers (clang, gcc, and Visual C++ all included).

If you want it on the heap then do this:

```
Structure * Create(int Parameter)
{
    Structure * structure = new Structure();
    return structure;
}
```

But it's better to use a smart pointer. If you're using c++11 you can use `std::unique_ptr`.

```
std::unique_ptr<Structure> Create(int Parameter)
{
    auto structure = std::unique_ptr<Structure>(new Structure());
    return structure;
}
```

Comment: You should mention that RVO is never guaranteed to happen.

Comment: @Angew Agreed, I've added that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it behave however you want.  If you define a function like this...

```
Structure* someFunction();
```

will return a pointer to a Structure object.  This object must be allocated with new.  For example defining the function like this:

```
Structure* someFunction() {
    Structure* someNewStructure = new Structure();
    return someNewStructure;
}
```

You have to remember that this element was created within this function, and the function is transferring "responsibility" for the destruction of this object on to the caller.  It is usually best to avoid this, though with large data structures it can't be.  Another way to handle this is to define a copy constructor in your class so that you can do it the way you referenced.  Without defining this copy constructor if you did this:

```
Sturcture someFunction() {
    Structure someResultStruct;
    return someResultStruct;
}
```

When you call someFunction in this case, if your class contained dynamic elements, or other complex data types, they are not guaranteed to copy correctly on return, and you will get weird behavior... unless you define your own copy constructor.